# Trying to upload multiple items to cosmos db

Tags: node.js, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

I'm trying to read a file line by line, once 500 lines are reached, I'm creating a cosmos db container client and uploading the data. So this way, I'm sharing a connection for each 500 lines.
Here's my code :

```
lineReader.eachLine(pathToFile, (line, last) => {
            lineCount += 1
            let insertItem = JSON.parse(line)
            linesList.push(insertItem)
            if (lineCount % 500 === 0) {
                //create copy of lineslist and empty the actual list
                let tempList = [...linesList]
                linesList = []
        
                getContainer('dummy2', 'type').then(container => {
                    tempList.map((lineToBeInserted, pos) => {
                        container.items.create(lineToBeInserted).then(dbItem => {
                            if (last) {
                                res.end('\r\n written all data to db')
                            } else {
                                res.write('writtem to db')
                            }
                        })
```

Here is my getContainer method in config :

```
async function getContainer(name, partitionKey) {

  partitionKey = "/" + partitionKey

  let pk = getConfig(name, partitionKey).partitionKey

  return _client
    .database(_databaseId)
    .containers.createIfNotExists({
      id: name,
      pk
    }, {
      offerThroughput: 5000
    }).then(container => {
      return _db.container(container.container.id)
    }).catch(err => {
      console.log(err)
    })

}
```

But I'm getting ETIMEDOUT error in the .create() method to create an item:

```
FetchError: request to https://brand-consumer-analytics-eastasia.documents.azure.com:443/dbs/quilt/colls/dummy2/docs failed, reason: connect ETIMEDOUT 23.102.239.134:443
    at ClientRequest.<anonymous> (D:\Polynomial Projects\Compare Blob with db\node_modules\node-fetch\lib\index.js:1461:11)    
    at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:315:20)
    at TLSSocket.socketErrorListener (_http_client.js:426:9)
    at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:315:20)
    at emitErrorNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:92:8)
    at emitErrorAndCloseNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:60:3)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:84:21) {
  type: 'system',
  errno: 'ETIMEDOUT',
  code: 'ETIMEDOUT',
  headers: {
    'x-ms-throttle-retry-count': 0,
    'x-ms-throttle-retry-wait-time-ms': 0
  }
}
```

Could not get a reason for this error. When I skip the line check and create a container client for each record, then the error will not show up.

Comment: Did you try reducing the line count like 400, 300, 200..? I suspect having 500 items might be overwhelming for the network. Looking the stacktrace, it looks like an error from node networking stack and not from CosmosDB side.

Comment: I'm confused. Are you creating a new container for every 500 items and then inserting the data into the new container?

Comment: Hi @krishg, yes I tried reducing the count but it did not work. Is there any way of increasing the timeout for the cosmos db ?

Comment: What does a sample `lineToBeInserted` look like? A json document?

Comment: Yes, a lineToBeInserted is a json document.